# How to get result of two tables in sql?

Tags: sql

These are my two tables:

- `Questions`: QuestionID, Question, SubjectID, Totalmarks, IsActive
- `RoundDetails`: CandidateID, QuestionID, MarksObtain

How to write query to get result of all questions details from `Questions` table and also result should display whether candidate attempt that question or not?

This is my query but I get only question attempted by candidate but I want both attempted and not attempted:

```
select 
   q.QuestionID, q.TotalMarks, q.Question, 
   isnull(rd.MarksObtained, 0) MarksObtained,
   convert(bit, isnull(rd.QuestionID, 0)) Attended
from 
   Questions q 
full join 
   RoundDetails rd on q.questionID = isnull(rd.QuestionID, q.questionID) 
where  
   q.SubjectID = 2 AND q.IsActive = 1 AND rd.CandidateID = 9
```

Comment: That is basic SQL. Please take a tutorial first.

Comment: I want query...! :-(

Comment: I try but not works..?

Comment: Please post what you tried and what the problem with that query is.

Comment: I tried in above query for candidate with id=9 and for subject of id = 2 and questions that are active.

Comment: Change your `ON` condition to `on q.questionID = rd.QuestionID AND rd.CandidateID = 9` and remove the `AND rd.CandidateID = 9` from your `WHERE`

Comment: Which dbms? (ISNULL and CONVERT are product specific...)

Comment: Yeah.... :-D, that what I want. Thanx Siyual! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that

```
AND rd.CandidateID = 9
```

on the `WHERE` clause effectively "kills" the full join by requiring that `RoundDetails` be present.

Move this part of the condition into the `ON` clause of the join, and replace the join with `LEFT OUTER`, because you do not need a full outer join anyway:

```
select
    q.QuestionID
,   q.TotalMarks
,   q.Question
,   isnull(rd.MarksObtained, 0) MarksObtained
,   convert(bit, isnull(rd.QuestionID, 0)) Attended
from Questions q
left outer join RoundDetails rd 
  ON q.questionID = q.questionID AND rd.CandidateID = 9
where
    q.SubjectID = 2 AND q.IsActive = 1
```

As a general rule, you should be extremely careful adding conditions on outer-joined tables in the `WHERE` clause, because any condition that is not null-preserving will convert your outer join to an inner join.

Comment: @kls You are welcome! If this solves the issue, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know that you have an answer, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Different SQL JOINs

INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables

LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table

RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table

## FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

As you are using Full Join you will only get the questions that have an answer attempted. you need to use a **Left Join** instead.
[take a look at the joins tutorials on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)